# How to find modulo inverse if two number are not relatively prime for Hill cipher?

Tags: cryptography

While practicing for Hill Cipher I choose a random Key matrix of $ 2*2 $ given as follows :
$ K = \begin{bmatrix}3&2\\1&0\\\end{bmatrix} $

Say the Text to Encrypt is **ATTACK** 
By using the Following Equation $ C=K * P \mod 26 $ I got the encrypted Text as **MAFTAC**, where

> $C$ is Cipher Text Matrix
>
> $K$ is Key Matrix
>
> $P$ is Plain Text Matrix

Now while decrypting the Cipher text using equation $ P= K ^{-1} * C \mod 26 $.

I need to find $ K^{-1} = |K|^{-1} Adj  A $ 
But The Multiplicative Inverse $ |K|^{-1}$  exist only if $ 26 $ and $|K|$ are relatively Prime. But In this case $|K|=-2= 24 \mod {26}$.

But 24 and 26 are not relatively Prime. Does That Mean The following Key Can't be used To Encrypt The Text?

Comment: @Moo So Does that mean there is one more rule to be always observed that whether determinant of key matrix is  coprime with 26 or not? which is not told usually in books. And this key matrix can't be used to find the key

Comment: Oh okay, thanks I will note it down. To use key matrix carefully otherwise you will stuck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your $K$ has determinant $-2$ which has a zero-divisor modulo $26$, hence $K$ has no inverse. It cannot be used as the key for a Hill cipher.

The function defined by $K$ is not injective: e.g. the plaintexts $\begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 13\\ \end{bmatrix}$ and  $\begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 0\\ \end{bmatrix}$ give the same ciphertext, so we cannot go back to the plain text from the ciphertext.

Comment: -2 can be converted to +24 by adding 26 see this https://crypto.interactive-maths.com/uploads/1/1/3/4/11345755/6449828_orig.jpg

Comment: @Gaurav it still means there’s no inverse though.

Comment: Yeah I agree , Though i was looking for good explanation, anyway i found it in comments above by Moo thanks for your explanation too

Comment: @Gaurav I added my own extra explanation as Moo's comment is gone.